# How to get the range of characters

Tags: javascript, fonts, svg, unicode-string, xml-entities

I am about to import SVG - Fonts with Javascript to be able to animate even single letters. Thereby i am storing the glyphs in an Javascript Object, where the Unicode-value of the glyph defines the key and the glyph itself becomes the value. So when i create text from a given string i use the each character from the string to get the suitable glyph for it.
And here comes my question:

The unicode-value of the glyphs unicode attribute ([specified here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#GlyphElementUnicodeAttribute)) can be an XML character reference in hexadecimal (`unicode="&#x66;&#x66;&#x6c;"`) or decimal (`unicode="&#102;&#102;&#108;`") notation. For the hkern- and vkern-elements (representing the kerning table) the characters given as Unicode Range ([specified here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/fonts.html#dataqual) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#HKernElementU1Attribute)). Is there any Library which could do the conversion from all these possible variations? Does anybody know a resource where i can find further information which could help me solving this problem?

The overall problem is to convert all possible variations of Input into a consistent list of unicode values i can use as Key for the glyph map.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create a hidden element with automatic width (css width:auto), place your string into it, and then measure (perhaps with Mootools) the width of that element?

Comment: I just tried this, and it works perfectly - remember to set the font attributes correctly, or copy them from the element which is the final destination of the text being measured.